# Login via Google in React application using Passportjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, authentication, passport.js, jwt

I`m working on project that contains 2 apps: web-site and chrome extension. Web-site technologies stack: `Nodejs`, `Mongoose`, `React`.

For now, I`m trying to realize authentication via Google+, using `Passportjs`. Why `Passportjs` ? Because I want to use many authentication flows.

First of all, I make a simple auth flow with login and password:

- on register, I add user to db.
- on logIn, I check user credentials from db. If all right, I send token to client and save it to localStorage. In future, I want to use token to authenticate user.

Why token? Because in chrome extension I need authentication too.

Look at my code: (files in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/CandyOgre/ee4650673e6920334b955d4fd07d49a3))

LogIn realization: 
`local-login.js` file

SignUp realization:
`local-signup.js` file

I have a login page, which makes AJAX request to server with login and password:
`LoginPage.jsx` file

When I tried to make authorization via Google I experienced some problems.
My Google authorization code:
`google-login.js` file

How I must return token to client? (for saving in `localStorage`) And, where I can get the right token? `accessToken`(parameter in passport callback) - is it that what I need?

Comment: Falling in same category. Any help from anyone?